# Compose two Traversals, with read-only access to the middle layer

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

I'd like to compose two traversals and then traverse the composition with something that also depends on the "middle" layer.

I think that would mean making an `IndexedTraversal` from the two `Traversal`s:

```
rememberMidpoint :: Traversal' s a -> Traversal' a b -> IndexedTraversal' a s b
```

Maybe the question can be simplified further to

```
remember :: Traversal' s a -> IndexedTraversal' s a a
```

or

```
remember :: Traversal' s a -> IndexedTraversal' a s a
```

?

So my questions are:

- Am I correct in wanting to use `IndexedTraversal` for this?
- If yes, how would I implement either `rememberMidpoint`, or one of the two `remember` functions + a way of composing their result with a non-indexed `Traversal`?

Comment: According to [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:IndexedTraversal), your intended `IndexedTraversal` is not legal, as the `a` index changes if you modify an innermost `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@phadej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308058/phadej) helped me out over on #haskell-lens, pointing me towards [`selfIndex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:selfIndex):

> Use a value itself as its own index. This is essentially an indexed version of `id`.

Together with the combinator [`<.`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#v:-60-.) to compose an indexed and a non-indexed traversal, we get:

```
rememberMidpoint :: Traversal' s a -> Traversal' a b -> IndexedTraversal' a s b
rememberMidpoint outer inner = outer . selfIndex <. inner
```

And to address [@András Kovács](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068232/andr%c3%a1s-kov%c3%a1cs)'s point in the comment:

> According to docs, your intended `IndexedTraversal` is not legal, as the `a` index changes if you modify an innermost `b`.

I don't believe this to be true: if I understand `selfIndex` right, the `a` in the index will stay the the "original" `a`, not become the one with the modified `b` inside.

Comment: The `selfIndex` doc in your link also says that it's improper for modification.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Hrmpf. Well in my case, I am going to use it via `reindexed f` s.t. `f` only depends on the non-`b` parts of the `a`. But I don't think there's a way to enforce this in general. However,that would make it not worse than `selfIndex`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Would making `inner` into an `IndexPreservingTraversal` help?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with this part of `lens`.

Comment: The note in the package is there for "correctness" and "lawfulness" guarantees, but it's very unlikely that it would ever cause you problems in practice. It's perfectly fine to use unlawful traversals, and in this particular case it's more of a technicality than anything :)

Regarding the `IndexPreservingTraversal`, that would allow you to replace `<.` with `.` but wouldn't change the behaviour or lawfulness in a meaningful way.